# Vaadin Flow Grid has no height

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

I have the following `Grid` showing Java system properties:

```
systemPropertyGrid = new Grid<>();
systemPropertyGrid.setItems(buildSystemProperties());
systemPropertyGrid.addColumn(SystemProperty::getProperty).setHeader("Property").setFlexGrow(1);
systemPropertyGrid.addColumn(SystemProperty::getValue).setHeader("Value").setFlexGrow(5);
systemPropertyGrid.setHeight("500px");
```

All items are shown when I replace the `setHeight` by `setHeightByRows(true)`. But as soon as I don't specify `systemPropertyGrid.setHeightByRows(true)` the grid has a calculated height of 2 pixels in the browser (Firefox, Edge) which is the border. However, the element style `height` is correctly set to `500px` as I can see in Firefox developer tools.

Bug in Vaadin Flow? How is this even possible that the browser doesn't use the element style `height` ultimately?

Screenshot:
[image: Grid that is filled with items and height set to 500px but is actually 2px high]

SSCCE using the Vaadin Flow spring starter:
[my-starter-project_51443246.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wydi9xku501sbw0/my-starter-project_51443246.zip?dl=0). Call maven goal springBoot:run.

Comment: What version of `vaadin` are you using? I just tested it with `10.0.1` and couldn't reproduce the problem. And what's the parent of the `Grid`?

Comment: @MehdiJavan I am using the same version. The parent is a VerticalLayout, and other Div and VerticalLayouts in the hierarchy. I will try to make an SSCCE and report back.

Comment: @MehdiJavan Can you have a look at the SSCCE? Does it show the Grid correctly with 200px height on your machine? Maybe you can share your project where it was working for you? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. It doesn't work in Firefox, while it works in Chrome. You can submit an issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/new).
As a workaround, if you set the height of the parent `VerticalLayout`, it works in both Chrome and Firefox. So, add the following statement:

```
setHeight("500px");
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in [Vaadin Grid v5.0.5](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/releases/tag/v5.0.5) which has been released as part of **Vaadin 10.0.9** or **Vaadin 11.0.4**. So you need to make sure to use either of those. (which of course wasn't released at the time of the original posting)